# Is gravitational length contraction only in one direction?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, observers

It makes sense to me that an object's length would contract due to gravity.  Consider a cube falling towards to the earth.  When it lands on the surface, gravity will compress it.  This seems to be in line with common sense observations about how gravity works without needing to know relativity.  So my question is this:  Will the length contract in all dimensions of the cube or will it only be in the vertical dimension?

Comment: Does it also make intuitive sense that the box contracts when while it is falling and no other "force" affect it other than gravity? I mean, all parts of the box are pulled almost equally, unless the box is unreasonably long.

Answer (score 1):

The length contraction would be in the radial direction, meaning that an object like a cube which is not fully rotationally symmetric would be distorted more on the parts which are closest to the earth. For a longer discussion on this see [Is there a space dilation due to gravity? or it is prohibited?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_a_space_dilation_due_to_gravity_or_it_is_prohibited).

Comment: That makes sense of course, but not exactly what I meant to ask.

Answer (score 1):

No, the gravitational fractional length contraction $(1-\frac{GM}{r})$ caused by a mass is not just in the radial direction.  The Schwarzschild metric shows there is also an equal fractional expansion $(1+\frac{GM}{r})$ in the time direction.

The fractional contraction $(1-h+)$ in one dimension (say x) and simultaneous equal fractional expansion $(1+h+)$ in another dimension (say y) is also done by the $h+$ polarization of a gravitational wave.  This effect is observed in LIGO.

I think this is saying that a small volume $d^4x$ is invariant when influenced by gravity.

Comment: So the cube would appear to shrink uniformly and not squash?

Comment: The 3-dimensional cube does not shrink uniformly.  It is mostly squashed in one direction (the radial one).  For a finite width cube there is a much smaller sidewise squash as both sides of the cube try to fall radially to the center of the gravitating mass ("tidal effect"). It is the 4-dimensional volume d(ct) dx dy dz which doesn't change.

Comment: So if you ignore all forces and concentrate only on gravitational length contraction, it happens radially, meaning the object is squashed in the vertical dimension towards the center of the planet only?